# "You need an appropriate loader to handle this file type...", jsx

Tags: webpack

I wanted to use react-pivot component, when I compile I am getting following errror

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-pivot/index.jsx 124:6
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (124:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
|     var html = (
>       <div className='reactPivot'>
| 
|       { this.props.hideDimensionFilter ? '' :
```